# Creating a loop with two variables in Python, where one variable only changes after every nth loop while the other changes with each loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program where I have two lists & one dictionary:

```
dict = {'fruit1' : 'apple', 'fruit2' :'banana', 'fruit3':'cherry' ....and so on} 
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e'....]
list2 = ['fruit1', 'fruit2','fruit3'....]
```

I have a program which looks like this. [This is not right at all, but it helps represent what I'm trying to get as the result].

```
for obj1 in list1:
    for obj_2 in list2:
        print(obj1)
        print(obj_2)
        print(dict[obj_2])
```

My need is to loop this in a way where `obj_2` changes every nth loop, but `obj_1` changes every loop. How can I achieve this?
So my result would look like(considering nth loop is 3rd loop):

```
a
fruit1
apple
b
fruit1
apple
c
fruit1
apple
d
fruit2
banana
e
fruit2
banana
f
fruit2
banana
g
fruit3
cherry
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter variable instead of nested loops. Increment the counter each time through the loop, and when it reaches `n` wrap it back to `0` and increment the index into `list2`.

```
n = 3
list2_index = 0
counter = 0
for obj1 in list1:
    obj_2 = list2[list2_index]
    print(obj1)
    print(obj_2)
    print(dict[obj_2])
    counter += 1
    if counter == n:
        counter = 0
        list2_index += 1
```

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Answer (score 1):

so all you have to do to achive is change the place of your two for loops.

```
#BTW it isn't adviced to use reserved keywords for variable names so dont use Dict for a variable name
myDict = {'fruit1' : 'apple', 'fruit2' :'banana', 'fruit3':'cherry'} 
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2 = ['fruit1', 'fruit2','fruit3']

#so in this nested loop obj2 only changs after  the n loops (n being the length of list1)
#which is after list1 is complete and it does that over and over 
#until list2 is complete
for obj2 in list2:
    for obj1 in list1:
        print(obj1)
        print(obj2)
        print(myDict[obj2])
```

**EDIT**
I might have misunderstood what you meant by third loop as @Barmar suggested. so if that is what you meant here is another piece of code.

```
myDict = {'fruit1' : 'apple', 'fruit2' :'banana', 'fruit3':'cherry'} 
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2 = ['fruit1', 'fruit2','fruit3']

#a variable to keep track of the nth loop
nthLoop = 1 
for obj2 in list2:
    for obj1 in list1:
        #if you print for three times which is what you wanted for your nthloop to be 
        #then break, which will break out of this nested loop allowing to only print 3 times and also set the 
        #nthLoop back to zero so that it will work nicely for the next iteration
        if nthLoop > 3:
            nthLoop = 0
            break
        print(obj1)
        print(obj2)
        print(myDict[obj2])
        nthLoop += 1
```

Comment: This prints `fruit1 apple` 5 times, not 3 times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
However, I'm trying to limit the print of "fruit1" to 3 times only, not based on the length of the list1
If we assume the list1 is 26 characters long

Comment: @user14131697 How about now? does the new solution answer your question